# wordpress show current category child function

Tags: php, wordpress

wordpress have function `the_category('');` for show all category assigned to te current post , but i need to get current category only child and not show parent .

for example my post have category  category parent --> category child and the_category; print :your post cat is : ( category parent , category child )

i neeed parint , your post cat is : (category child) and not show parent .

Comment: your question is quite difficult to understand - please rephrase it.

Comment: no is very simple i need to get current category child in loop single page in wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) function , witch will return all categories asigned to a post ( this means all parents and childs allso ) so you can loop thru them and see witch one is parent and witch one is child and print the one you're trying to get . I suggest you build a function in you're theme functions file.

---

Update

For example let's say you whant to display the child category name in you're single.php theme file so you would do this:

```
<?php $child_category = post_child_category(get_the_ID()); ?>
<?php if ( $child_category ) echo $child_category->cat_name; ?>
```

In order for that to work you need to define `post_child_category` function in you're theme functions file ( if you look in you're theme directory you'll see a functions.php file , if not then you can create it now ) , so you would add the following :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_child_category' ) )
{
    function post_child_category( $id = null )
    {
        if ( $id = null )
            return false;

        $categories = get_the_category( $id );
        if ( count($categories) > 0 )
        {
            return $categories[count($categories)-1];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update

If you whant to display the category link you would do this :

```
<?php $child_category = post_child_category(get_the_ID()); ?>
    <?php if ( $child_category ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($child_category->cat_ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $child_category->cat_name;?>">
            <?php echo $child_category->cat_name;?>
        </a>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: yes i like this way but i Do not know who to build a function in you're theme functions file .

Comment: +1, it should be easier with get_the_category than wp_list_categories, you just have to test category_parent attributes

Comment: ohhh ! one point is problem this is true every things but, this is only text and not linkd , i want to link this !

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>    
<?php
        $blogCategoryID = "5"; // current category ID
        $childCatID = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE parent=$blogCategoryID");
        if ($childCatID){
            foreach ($childCatID as $kid)
            {
                $childCatName = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name, term_id FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$kid");
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $childCatName->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo $childCatName->name; ?></a></li>
           <?php
            }
        }

    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories

Comment: i see this page but this is get category by id or name , i need get current category

Comment: are you shure wp_list_categories will show categories assigned to a post ?

Comment: my problem is Isolation parents and child .

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
$catID=$wp_query->query_vars['cat'];
$args = array('parent' => $catID);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"  ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </li> ';
}
```